# SQL: Taking column with varchar array, adding elements together and converting the result to float

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

In Amazon Redshift, I have a table with varchar column that contains values in the following format: `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]`.

I want to insert that column into another table, but with a summary (as a float, e.g. `6.0`) instead of varchar array (`[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]`). Is it possible to calculate sum of field?

Here is a sample to better illustrate the problem:

**Table 1:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS weather.precipitation_data
(
    record_import_datetime        timestamp,
    location_id                   varchar(10),
    hourly_precipitation          varchar(1000)
)
SORTKEY (location_id);
```

Looks like this:

```
record_import_datetime     | location_id | hourly_precipitation
2023-04-25 19:00:00.000000 | STATION001  | [0.0, 1.0, 2.8]
2023-04-25 19:00:00.000000 | STATION002  | [0.0, 0.0, 1.2]
```

**Table 2:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS weather.daily_summary
(
    record_import_datetime        timestamp,
    location_id                   varchar(10),
    daily_precipitation           int4
)
SORTKEY (location_id);
```

Should look like this:

```
record_import_datetime     | location_id | daily_precipitation
2023-04-25 19:00:00.000000 | STATION001  | 3.8
2023-04-25 19:00:00.000000 | STATION002  | 1.2
```

How do I write that JOIN query?

```
INSERT INTO weather.daily_summary (
    location_id,
    daily_precipitation)
SELECT
    t1.location_id
    SUM(t1.hourly_precipitation)::float --pseudocode
FROM weather.precipitation_data t1
JOIN weather.daily_summary t2
    ON t1.location_id = t2.location_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the real issue is actually performing the "SUM" of the values in the varchar.  There are a number of ways to do this.  The most straight forward way, assuming that the varchar always follows this format, would be to just add the values extracted by string position.  There's no need for joining here as this is just an insert.

```
    INSERT INTO weather.daily_summary (
        location_id,
        daily_precipitation)
    SELECT
        t1.location_id
        substring(t1.hourly_precipitation, 2, 3)::float + 
          substring(t1.hourly_precipitation, 7, 3)::float + 
          substring(t1.hourly_precipitation, 12, 3)::float  as daily_precipitation
    FROM weather.precipitation_data t1;
```

Now this will be brittle and if the format of hourly_percipitation changes slightly then this will break.  The good news is that if this is from an automated then the format usually doesn't change.  You can make the substring logic a bit smarter but this likely won't be iron-clad.

You can use Redshift's json functions to do the same thing.

```
INSERT INTO weather.daily_summary (
    location_id,
    daily_precipitation)
SELECT
    t1.location_id
    json_extract_array_element_text(t1.hourly_precipitation, 0)::float + 
      json_extract_array_element_text(t1.hourly_precipitation, 1)::float + 
      json_extract_array_element_text(t1.hourly_precipitation, 2)::float  as daily_precipitation
FROM weather.precipitation_data t1;
```

This has the advantage of relying on the JSON format of the string but this function is Redshift specific so your SQL will be less portable.  The string will need to stay in the same JSON format with the same number of elements.

You could convert this string to a SUPER data type and expand it though the build in functions in Redshift.  I won't write this out as there are good examples online. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html

There are other methods as well but that is likely enough for now.